# convert HTML to json in python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am trying to convert HTML table to json using beautifulsoup() function python, i was able to convert some other tables to json but this is of different kind.

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
[{
    "name": "abc",
    "age": "21",
    "sex": "m",
    "loction": "us",
    "language": "en"
}, {
    "name": "xyz",
    "age": "25",
    "sex": "f",
    "loction": "us",
    "language": "en"
}]
```

Table is :

```
<table><colgroup><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /></colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th><span>name</span></th>
<th><span>age</span></th>
<th><span>sex</span></th>
<th><span>location</span></th>
<th><span>language</span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">
<p><span>abc</span></p>
</td>
<td colspan="1"><span>21</span></td>
<td colspan="1"><span>m</span></td>
<td colspan="1">us</td>
<td colspan="1">en</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">
<p><span>xyz</span></p>
</td>
<td colspan="1"><span>25</span></td>
<td colspan="1">f</td>
<td colspan="1">us</td>
<td colspan="1">en</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Some help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course, make a list of dictionaries manually, but we can also do it without doing 0 explicit HTML parsing at all by transitioning through a `pandas.DataFrame` using [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html):

```
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd

data = """your HTML"""

df = pd.read_html(data, flavor="lxml")[0]

new_header = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df.columns = new_header

pprint(df.to_dict('records'))
```

Prints:

```
[{'age': '21', 'language': 'en', 'location': 'us', 'name': 'abc', 'sex': 'm'},
 {'age': '25', 'language': 'en', 'location': 'us', 'name': 'xyz', 'sex': 'f'}]
```

Comment: I have a problem installing pandas, it has a dependency on numpy which wont install with this error.

 DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library to convert HTML to JSON which can do this: [html-to-json](https://github.com/fhightower/html-to-json).

You can installing the library using [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/html-to-json/). Once the library is installed, you would run:

```py
import html_to_json

s = '''<table><colgroup><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /></colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th><span>name</span></th>
<th><span>age</span></th>
<th><span>sex</span></th>
<th><span>location</span></th>
<th><span>language</span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">
<p><span>abc</span></p>
</td>
<td colspan="1"><span>21</span></td>
<td colspan="1"><span>m</span></td>
<td colspan="1">us</td>
<td colspan="1">en</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">
<p><span>xyz</span></p>
</td>
<td colspan="1"><span>25</span></td>
<td colspan="1">f</td>
<td colspan="1">us</td>
<td colspan="1">en</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>'''


html_to_json.convert_tables(s)
```

And this will give you (the `\n` around values for the `name` key are because the `<td>` containing each name has newlines in it):

```json
[
  [
    {
      "name": "\nabc\n",
      "age": "21",
      "sex": "m",
      "location": "us",
      "language": "en"
    },
    {
      "name": "\nxyz\n",
      "age": "25",
      "sex": "f",
      "location": "us",
      "language": "en"
    }
  ]
]
```

Hope this is helpful!